# ETH from Rinkeby to Poloniex Not Credited

Tags: rinkeby

I sent 1 ETH from my Rinkeby to Poloniex account on 18 Dec. It is withdrawn from Rinkeby on 18th itself, but still not shown in Deposits of Poloniex account (as on 9 Jan). I am able to see that ETH in Etherscan account checker. I have raised a ticket with Poloniex Support but they have not responded still. Please help me retrieve by ETH. The transaction hash is `0xcadd372f2b280b37dcd6328bf1f4160770858da7da0fd7addfa8c8086e084bdb`.

P.S.: I see that other similar questions have been closed as being off-topic, if mine is also that case please guide me another forum to post this. Also I wanted to understand if this transaction from Rinkeby is any different from other questions.

Your help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Would really love to understand your thinking - why you think this should be possible - interesting.

Comment: @ligi someone lead him to the wrong direction or trying to do some scam IMO.

Comment: I am just a newbie to cryptocurrency technology, someone transferred me the ETH to Rinkeby and then I transferred to Poloniex. All this I learnt & did on a single day. I really do not know if this is possible or not. Is there any way to recover that amount. I see that my Poloniex ETH address is credited but just that it is not reflected in Poloniex Balance.

Comment: Rinkeby ether is just test-ether - you can get it for free here: https://faucet.rinkeby.io - no real need to recover enythig

Comment: @ligi, I am sorry if I ask too obvious questions. "Rinkeby ether is a free ether" - Does that mean is there no real value tied to Rinkeby ether?What I meant by recover is, the ETH is transferred from Rinkeby to Poloniex - so it is deducted from Rinkeby balance but NOT credited to Poloniex. How to make Poloniex reflect this balance OR any other method?

Answer (score 3):

> I wanted to understand if this transaction from Rinkeby is any
>   different from other questions.

Rinkeby - is a testnet network, the coins in that [`network cost`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Play_money) nothing and you cant sent coins from testnet to mainnet.